# Android emulator doesn't load - "waiting too long for mReady"

Tags: android, android-emulator

So Android continues to act bizzarely. I've run the application on emulator for zillion times and suddenly I can't do it any more. I haven't changed anything in the program.

I get tons of these messages:

```
01-03 03:56:50.595: DEBUG/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9798 objects / 461152 bytes in 308ms

01-03 03:56:50.595: DEBUG/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9798 objects / 461152 bytes in 308ms

01-03 03:56:50.595: DEBUG/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9798 objects / 461152 bytes in 308ms
```

along with:

```
01-03 04:05:16.455: WARN/MountService(88): Waiting too long for mReady!
```

Any ideas?

### Edit

Some new error appeared:

```
Failed to upload Info.apk on device 'emulator-5554'
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found

SDK Manager] Warning: Error parsing 'C:\Program Files\android-sdk-    windows\platforms\android-5\sdk.properties': java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-5\sdk.properties (The system cannot find the file specified).

SDK Manager] Warning: Error parsing 'C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-6\sdk.properties': java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-6\sdk.properties (The system cannot find the file specified).
```

How can this file be missing is beyond me, since I didn't mess with it.

Comment: Are you trying to do something with the SD card when you have it plugged in with a USB cable?

Comment: I'm developing the app with Android SDK 2.2, and I don't use USB. It's a problem with the emulator. I updated my post:)

Comment: It's not our problem that it's urgent. But none of those are errors. Those are all warnings and really have nothing to do with your app.

Comment: It's definitely my problem. Good to clear that up. As for the errors here they are http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/4751/logq.jpg although I can't deduce anything from there, and I'm pretty sure I had them before, when I didn't have this problem and could run the app. another edit: I didn't post any code because, as I said, it worked and then the next time it just stopped working without any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing a lot of allocation messages and freeing messages I think your code is thrashing the memory by allocating tons of memory, freeing it, GC runs (you see your messages), then you keep doing that over and over.

If your program was running, you made a change, and it started acting like this then I would bet your last change caused it.  You should probably do a compare between your last changes using local change history and revert it to see if that fixes it.  Other options are putting some breakpoints on your startup activity and see what portion of the code is hogging the CPU or taking too long.

It's not Android behaving any weirder than it normally does.  That's your code. :-)

Comment: I'm 99% :D sure it's not the code, it was just some simple if clause, I reverted it but the problem remains. I got some new error warnings (somehow) so I will add them to my initial post, maybe it'll reveal something to you. Btw I started with Android programming 5 days ago, so I'm aware that it's a mess and could be improved immensely. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dronevil you're not going to figure this problem out looking at the logs from the emulator.  The logs are verbose and not every sentence is a real error you have to pay attention to.  Case in point that MoutService message has nothing to do with your program.  You're not giving us much to go on here.  I'd add some log statements in your activity startup and see if those are making it into the logs.  Try and see where your program is getting to before everything stalls out.  Check the CPU usage is it 100%?  That would be a problem.  Finally try uninstalling your app from the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try [creating a new Android Virtual Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) (AVD), then reconfigure your IDE to use the new AVD instead of the old one.